# How are inbox drivers identified on Windows

Tags: windows, device-driver

The Deployment Image Servicing and Management API (dismapi.dll) (and the Powershell command Get-WindowsDriver) can be used to identify inbox drivers, i.e. drivers deployed with the Windows installation.

How does the API determine that a driver is an inbox driver? Is it something in the registry or something in the file system?

(The reason I'm asking is that I want to create a tool that helps identify dependencies between legacy proprietary applications and drivers. An out of box driver is a candidate for investigation. Unfortunately I need a tool that will run on XPSP3 and above. dismapi.dll is not compatible with that OS.)

Comment: Ah, I see this question got voted down. Sorry if this is a bad question. Can you give me some pointers to improve this and future questions? Happy to delete if it doesn't belong on SO for some reason.

Comment: I've edited the question to make it more focused in case that was a problem.

Comment: Thanks @Hans Passant, I'll investigate. I did describe it more fully in my initial question but it got voted down for some reason. I tried to simplify it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output of Get-WindowsDriver, all drivers listed with Inbox = false are inf files of the form oem*.inf.

Comment: Most `oem*.inf` are not in-box drivers, though.

Comment: Sorry, got my logic inverted! Now edited. Thanks @BenVoigt.